# Why do we have multiple color declarations for Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Shouldn't the palette theme update also affect other elements on the app such as buttons?

If we write this:

```
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
  },
})
```

Buttons components will not change to the primary color created. Also, if I create a box and provide the following:

`<Box color='primary.main'>primary.main</Box>`

it wont change the color of the text unless I do the following

`<Box color='palette.primary.main'>primary.main</Box>`

Is there a logistic behind it? I am assuming it has something to do with the auto change of colors when going to a different hue or dark but I am not 100% certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must access the main property to change it :

```
import blue from '@material-ui/core/colors/blue';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main : blue,
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I was originally confused by the declarations on this documentation page https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/